# What's the consequence if someone know the table name or field name in a database of mysql?

Tags: security

What's the consequence if  someone know the table name or field name in a database of mysql ? And they don't know the manager's pwd and username .Does it will be attacked easily?

Comment: Based on just that information it's not likely. It must be combined with something else.

Comment: Likely None. If you have a SQL injection vulnerability that allows this information to be exploited then the information will be retrievable from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a security question, it seems. For an application facing the public web, you need to practice security in depth.

To answer your question: No. Trying to secure a database by obfuscating column and table names is not usually used as part of security-in-depth.

Your web application should be built to avoid SQL injection and other exploits. That's a big topic which you can look up.

Your MySQL database machine itself should not be visible from the public network; it should be on an internal network in your web data center.  That keeps script kiddies from using their own MySQL client software from finding it or connecting to it.

The user name and password for the web application's access to the MySQL database should be kept reasonably secret. It's hard to keep those completely secret, because your web app has to use them a lot.

The web application's user name should give access only to the features of MySQL which it needs to do its job. A MySQL user can be denied the privilege of, for example, creating a view, droppping a table, or creating a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a security risk, since they will not be able to get into your database. If they can get into your database, then they don't need to know the tablename, because they can retrieve it from the database itself.
So the most important thing is to keep your database secure, use strong username/password combo's with restricted access for the different profiles. Make sure your websites are safe for SQL-Injection etcetera.

Comment: if I publish some fields name or table name for some reasons .And how?